# How to create jar in Blackberry Eclipse

Tags: java, blackberry, jar

How we can create a complete package to jar file , so we can use all functionality s of the particular package in another application .
What I am doing is , I am selecting all the java files (in a particular package) and right click and select Export option and then select jar and follow other steps ..finally I am getting  jar file ..but this is not working in my Blackberry project..

Comment: what about exporting the whole project? If you just export .java files I think the classPath with the declared main is missing.

Comment: @Simulant ..buddy I am following this link http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Ftasks-33.htm ..and able to genrat the jar  file but it's not working in Blackberry\

Comment: @Simulant :- I tested the jar file , that is working in JAVA SDK  ..the project compile & execute fine

Answer (score 4):

You can make a BlackBerry project into a **library** project pretty easily.

If you're using the Eclipse plugin, then your BlackBerry project should have a BlackBerry_App_Descriptor.xml file.  Open that in Eclipse, and on the **Application** tab, select **Application type** and then **Library**.

If you edit that xml file manually, you'll have something like this:

```xml
<Properties ModelVersion="1.1.2">
  <General Title="" Version="1.0.0" Vendor="BlackBerry Developer" Description=""/>
  <Application Type="Library" 
               MainMIDletName="" MainArgs="" HomeScreenPosition="0" StartupTier="7" IsSystemModule="true" IsAutostartup="false"/>
```

If you are using the old JDE toolset, [here are some instructions](http://blackberry-tips-bikas.blogspot.com/2010/02/how-to-create-library-jar-file-and-use.html).

Your library project should not have a `public static void main(String[] args)` method, like a normal App project.

Comment: ..thanks for the answer , I got the answer from this blogpost :- http://testberry.blogspot.in/2012/04/create-and-use-preverified-jar-files-in.html  ... I follow the steps mentioned in the blogpost and successfull getting jar file. And it's working in another application too..!!